# Get data using useeffect hook in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple page editor, When a user clicks edit page it opens an editor. I am passing the ID of the page using redux which will be used to get data from API.

Here is my Editor.

```
const [pageData, setPageData] = useState("");

  const getPage = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get(`/landing_pages/${id}`);
      console.log("page", response.data); // displays data at the end
      setPageData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    getPage(pageID);

    console.log('Page Data', pageData) // displays nothing

    let LandingPage = pageData;

     const editor = grapesjs.init({
       container: "#editor",
       components: LandingPage.components || LandingPage.html,
     })

  }, [pageID, getPage])
```

Why is Page Data display nothing even though the data from API is returned and is displayed in the console at the end? what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `getPage` is async, you need to wait for `getPage` to finish inside of the `useEffect` hook

Comment: @Tom can you show via code if you dont mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you `await` your `getPage` call, the updated `pageData` won't be available until the next render cycle so your assignment to `LandingPage` will be one cycle behind.

You should instead update in one `useEffect` and watch for changes to `pageData` in another.

```
const [pageData, setPageData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPage = async (id) => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get(`/landing_pages/${id}`);
        console.log("page", response.data); // displays data at the end
        setPageData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    getPage(pageID);
  }, [pageID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Page Data', pageData); // displays updated pageData

    let LandingPage = pageData;

    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: "#editor",
      components: LandingPage.components || LandingPage.html,
    });
  }, [pageData]);
```

Comment: Plichard adding Pagedata as a dependency will cause another rerender right?

Comment: No, because you aren't calling anything within that useEffect that would trigger one.